# How to give access to a "private" machine to send logs through EC2Config service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, amazon-cloudwatch

Hi have a db machine that isn't reachable from the outside world less you're the front-end connected to the db. It's on a private subnet.

Meanwhile, I want to configure EC2Config service to send logs from the machine to AWS Cloudwatch. The issue is that I don't know how to configure a rule in the subnet to allow that.

I've already associated an internet gateway but when I remote desktop the machine it displays no internet connection on windows. I'm a rookie on this. Can you help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new role like this:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAccessToSSM",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudwatch:PutMetricData",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:DescribeLogStreams",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and assign it to your instance. You will also need to modify the JSON file located in C:\Program Files\Amazon\Ec2ConfigService\Settings and restart the EC2Config service. 
Make sure that your instance has a public IP if you want it to connect to the Internet.

Comment: I've also needed to add new ports in the VPC subnet network ACL to allow outbound HTTPS and inbound ephemeral ports. Thanks!